# Need a clarification between JMS and REST based on following scenario

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jms

If Application A and Application B use REST, when Application B needs a service to get done from Application A (like calling a method in Application A), Application B can simply call the service or send a request for that service when ever it needs. Like wise what is the situation if Application A and Application B use JMS instead of REST, Can the Application B request for a message from Application A when it needs, or with JMS it is not possible to make a request/ask for a message ?

Comment: This question is far too broad. But one information to consider: HTTP based requests (such as REST) are modelling a _synchronous_ call, whereas JMS is inherently _asynchronous_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a very high level using JMS you can create queues and have listeners on it

So say you can have a two queues per application(a requestQ and responseQ).I'll explain the functioning from the perspective Application A wants to make a call to application B.

1. So when application A wants to interact with B it will post a
   message to its requestQ.
2. You can have something like [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) listening to this
   endpoint. When it receives the message it processes it and call the
   rest endpoint using Camel's [HTTP Component](http://camel.apache.org/http.html).
3. On success or error camel can post the response to A's responseQ using the Camel's [JMS component](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html), from where the application can pick it and do something about it.

This is a very crude design to explain the workings, and the architecture can differ based on requirement, but some of the benefits you get using this patterns are:

- Failover : What if B is down when A is trying to make the call? You can preserve the request in the requestQ and retry later.
- Asynchronicity.
- Things like system B can be slower than A in responding. In this case A doesn't have to wait.
- Fine grained control on the flow of data.

This in itself is a pretty broad topic. I would recommend reading about *Enterprise Integration Patterns* and *Apache Camel* for better understanding.

Comment: @techshare: By asynchronicity I meant that, like in calling conventional rest service, you will have to wait for the response to come back and this model won't scale well because with each thread you will be blocking resources(like threads etc )

Answer (score 0):

With JMS you cannot request any service from another application and wait for the processed request's response to come back. But if the only concern is to publish or send some message to another application then JMS is best as you don't have to wait for any response to come back from there. Simple send a message by JMS architecture to a defined Queue or Topic. The other application would just read the message from the Queue or Topic. But if you need any particular service to be executed and a valid response is mandatory, REST architecture would be suitable. So for request-response framework, REST is the best alternative.